# How to use std::fstream, boost, or anything else to create a folder file

Tags: file, serialization, boost, stl, directory

Hey i just learned about STL i/o, which lead me to boost::Serialize and Archive, and so i'm pretty much know how make any kind of file, except a **Folder** to hold/collect my formed files.

**How do i use code to create a Folder? preferably using boost::Serialize or the STL?**
*It would be great if it was platform-independent too!*

---

Ok now i've looked at/attempted to use boost::filesystem. However i when looking at the refrence documentation, there isn't that much info on create_directory();
I'm left with questions like: what if the directory already exists?

> bool create_directory(const path& p); bool create_directory(const
>   path& p, system::error_code& ec); Effects: Attempts to create the
>   directory p resolves to, as if by POSIX mkdir() with a second argument
>   of S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO.
>
> Postcondition: is_directory(p)
>
> Returns: true if a new directory was created, otherwise false.
>
> Throws: As specified in Error reporting.

I'm trying to run the following code, and checking whether a new folder, or what i now understand as a directory =), has been created. I can't find one! why? And it returns true =/

```
  path testPath("C:\\Users\\Howlett\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\boost tests\\newFolderTest");
  bool success = create_directory(testPath);
  bool success2= create_directory("C:\\Users\\Howlett\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\boost tests\\Test\\NestedFolderTest");
```

Comment: You don't mention whether the function returns true or false.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas it does return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should look for a *filesystem* library that might *boost* your productivity at this task. It might even be called [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) ;)

It's a pretty good library for handling filesystem stuff. Your specific task would be covered by `boost::filesystem::create_directory`.

---

The following source code works. If it doesn't create a directory, then you should refresh Windows Explorer to make sure that it's actually looking. If you run the program twice, the second time will print an error message.

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    fs::path thePath = fs::current_path();
    std::cout << thePath << std::endl;

    fs::path newDir = thePath / "newDir";
    std::cout << newDir << std::endl;

    bool bDidCreate = fs::create_directory(newDir);

    if(!bDidCreate)
        std::cout << "Directory creation failed!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i'm still a little confused! could you look at my edit to the question?